# Entity Reference getting data to view

Tags: views, entities

Content type A:

Title
Address
Geocodes

Content type B:

Student Name
Major
University (This is prepopulated basing on Title of Content type A)

Now on the page which displays data from Content type B, I need to get the geocodes of Content type A, basing on University selected. How do I do this?

I have to get them to views-view-field-content-type-b-block-field-university.tpl.php where I am using the geocodes to display the data on a google map.

I am very new to Drupal, so any help would be hugely helpful. TIA.